# Textview com letra riscada

Tags: android, textview

como posso obter este resultado `̶W̶a̶l̶l̶a̶c̶e̶ ̶R̶o̶b̶e̶r̶t̶o̶c̶` igual esta no nome da primeira lista abaixo...
o da lista esta riscado porque fiz no lado do servidor..
a intenção e deixar o resultado da tabela do meio riscada já que não faz parte do calculo enfim...agradeço desde já.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve usar o código abaixo:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Dessa forma seu texto ficará riscado.

Comment: perfeito! Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Outra solução que funciona em Views que não possuem as PaintFlags:

```
tv.setText(s, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable spannable = (Spannable) tv.getText();
spannable.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```